# Hang of List of schemes

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation

I want to align the second line of long names in a list of schemes like in the second screenshot below.

Current situation:

[image]

I want it like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi erkunt, welcome to TeX.sx. I've inserted the pictures into your question and also tried to edit the question to make it clearer what you're asking. I hope that's okay for you. It would be great if you could edit your question to include a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so people can see how you generate your indices. This will make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Let me add the following: it would be helpful if you provided information about the documentclass you're using (article, report, book, etc), the value of the `\textwidth` variable, how the "scheme" environment is defined (as a floating object, say), and how schemes are numbered (per section, per chapter).

Answer (score 1):

I can manage this problem by using `\hangindent`.

my .def file was

```
\def\@myschemedottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
\vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
{\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
\parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
\interlinepenalty\@M
\leavevmode
\@tempdima #3\relax
\advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
{Scheme #4}\nobreak
\leaders\hbox{$\m@th
\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
mu$}\hfill
\nobreak
\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
\par}%
}
```

I added `\hangindent=3.5pc` below `\parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue` and that solves my problem.

```
\def\@myschemedottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
\vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
{\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
\parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
\hangindent=3.5pc
\interlinepenalty\@M
\leavevmode
\@tempdima #3\relax
\advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
{Scheme #4}\nobreak
\leaders\hbox{$\m@th
\mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
mu$}\hfill
\nobreak
\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
\par}%
}
```